# show git branches with date of last commit

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

I was working on a branch a couple of weeks ago but I can't remember what the branch was called (there are many). I'd like to be able to do something like:

`git branch --print-last-commit`

and for it to output something like:

```
branch 1 - 2017-02-12
branch 2 - 2016-12-30
```

etc.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This will print **BranchName - CommitMessage - Date as (YYYY-MM-DD)**. You can manipulate/edit this command line to suit your need.

```
git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(HEAD) %(color:yellow)%(refname:short)%(color:reset) - %(contents:subject) - %(authorname) (%(color:green)%(committerdate:short)%(color:reset))'
```

Note that it will print for all local branches, not just current branch. You can create an alias for convenience.

```
[alias]
       branchcommits = !git for-each-ref --sort=committerdate refs/heads/ --format='%(HEAD) %(color:yellow)%(refname:short)%(color:reset) - %(contents:subject) - %(authorname) (%(color:green)%(committerdate:short)%(color:reset))'
```

and run **git branchcommits** in git bash prompt.

[image]

Comment: How would you filter the results? it is possible with `git log`, e.g `--author="Saurav"` or  `--after="2022-06-01 15:00"`

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, though with the help of other answers, I came out with another solution that does not involve a bash for loop.

```
$ paste  <(git branch | xargs -I {} git --no-pager show -q --format="%ci %cr" {} | tail -n +1) \
    <(git branch) | sort -h | tail -5
2021-10-12 11:24:21 -0700 2 weeks ago     adamryman/foobar
2021-10-12 15:20:18 -0700 2 weeks ago     adamryman/foobarbaz
2021-10-26 16:46:25 -0700 3 days ago      adamryman/baz
2021-10-27 19:00:14 -0700 2 days ago      adamryman/foobaz
2021-10-28 14:03:48 -0700 21 hours ago    adamryman/barfoo
```

Answer (score 1):

Command to show local branch in format "branch - Commit message - commit user (commit date). Use -r option for remote branches.

```
git branch --format='%(HEAD) %(color:yellow)%(refname:short)%(color:reset) - %(contents:subject) - %(authorname) (%(color:green)%(committerdate:short)%(color:reset))'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to get all last commit per branch

```
for branch in `git branch -r | grep -v HEAD`;do echo -e `git show --format="%ci %cr" $branch | head -n 1` \\t$branch; done | sort -r
```

More info at https://gist.github.com/jasonrudolph/1810768